# How to hide a tag in IE8 using CSS while printing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

To hide a button while printing, I am using the following embedded CSS. It works perfectly fine for Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE8.

```
 "<style type='text/css' media='all'> 
  input[type='button']{ 
     display:none !important;
  } 
  </style>"
```

Not sure why display:none property is not applying to the button in IE8.
I also tried replacing `media='all'` with `media='print'`, but still, not successful.
Can anyone please suggest me the change I need to make it compatible in IE8.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think IE8 understands `[type='button']`, or at least it may need a specific doctype to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check for any other alternative for specifying selector

Comment: The problem here is that IE8 doesn't support media queries. As far as I know it supports Attribute selectors, but in order to get it to respond to your media queries, you'll want to use something like [respondjs](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) which polyfills the support for media queries in earlier browsers that don't support it natively.